# What is [e.RowIndex] and working of [e.RowIndex]. Explain in brief

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new in asp.net technologies I don't understand the right meaning of the code specially mention below, please explain to me thank you in advance.

1. what is the working of e in this code.

   ```
   protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)    
   {       
       int eno, es;

       string en, ed;

       eno =Convert.ToInt32(((Label)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lb1"))).Text);

       en = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("t1"))).Text;
       ed = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("t2"))).Text;
       es=Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("t3"))).Text);
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
       con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
       con.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("updemp",con);
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eno", eno);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@en", en);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ed", ed);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@es", es);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   ```

Comment: Google is your friend:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewdeleteeventargs.rowindex?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the e corresponds to the signature of the event pattern, the standard pattern says you receive from a delegate (object sender, EventArgs e), in this case you have an event for every time a row is updated. And the e.RowIndex corresponds to the index of the row being updated, the e has other properties, such as the new value or the old value. For further reasearch I recommend microsft docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

As the object suggests (GridViewUpdateEventArgs) 'e' stands for the events relating to the update of a grid view. You can get similar method signatures that relate to other events such as deletions etc.

The 'RowIndex' relates to the index of the row on which this event was fired. So the code shown is getting 4 things based on the row that is being updated; the text from the label control called "lbl"and the text from the textbox controls called "t1", "t2" and "t3". These values are then being passed into a sql stored procedure as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

`GridView_RowUpdating` event fires when row's Update button clicked

using `e.RowIndex` finding the controls from Gridview for the row which is going to update.

Following this below link for deep learning :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating?view=netframework-4.8